# MVC Core 2.2 cannot find MaxJsonDeserializerMembers

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working in project that I need to use to get products data by category .The problem is when I get the products data it is big data it is around 16000 record when I sent it back to ajax call it hangs .So I think the problem from json MaxJsonDeserializerMembers property witch I cannot find in mvc core2.2.
I found Solution  that said add this line

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000"/>
```

to webconfig but in mvc core 2.2 there is no webconfig.

Comment: MaxJsonDeserializerMembers is a part of asp.net MVC, not with asp.net core. you can use JSON serializer `JsonSerializer ` to achieve it.

Comment: Did you try to use postman to send the data and check the result? What is your scenario of using ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8273) , as JamesNK said in that discussion , **There is no equivalent to aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers in Json.NET. The only limit is depth.**